# How to get Joint js rappid template

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I am working on a flow chart project and I've found joint js very useful. I need same template that they are using for rappid.

I tried to start working by reading its manual and its so vast. Is there any free template for rappid so to start with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rappid template if you purchase their Rappid product.  Rappid is built on top of Joint.  Rappid includes a bunch of modules that you can use with joint to make things easier and much more interesting.  When you purchase the Rappid product, you get a nice Rappid template in the source code drop.

Rappid API - http://www.jointjs.com/rappid/docs

About Rappid - http://www.jointjs.com/about-rappid